# SQL ColdFusion Get id from database and than update a row with form field value

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I have a query that needs to update `What_name` with whatever I type in the form. This is a snippet of my code:

```
<cfelseif ARGUMENTS.myForm.Submit EQ "Update_what">
    <cfquery name="LOCAL.myURL" datasource="#SERVER.cfc.core.getDSN()#">
        SELECT What_name 
        from logboek.tbl_What 
        WHERE What_name = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ARGUMENTS.myForm.What_name#" />
    </cfquery>
    <cfif LOCAL.myURL.RecordCount eq 1>
        <cfreturn VARIABLES.Error.myReturn />   
    <cfelse>
        <cfquery name="LOCAL.myURL" datasource="#SERVER.cfc.core.getDSN()#">
            UPDATE tbl_What
            SET What_name=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ARGUMENTS.myForm.Update_what#" />;
            WHERE What_name=<cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.myForm.What_name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> 
        </cfquery>
    </cfif>
```

I am getting the following error:

> Message
>   string    Component [cms_core.com.blog.blog] has no accessible Member with name [ERROR]

Is there something wrong with my query?

Comment: Your cfreturn tag is trying to return `variables.error.myReturn`.  There is nothing you posted that defines that variable.

Comment: Since you have asked another question it seems you have resolved this issue. Please add an answer so other users can see the solution. Cross reference to new question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/34878305/1636917