# ColdFusion SQL update with form

Tags: sql, coldfusion

```
<cfelseif ARGUMENTS.myForm.Submit EQ "Update_what">
    <cfquery name="LOCAL.myURL" datasource="#SERVER.cfc.core.getDSN()#">
        SELECT What_name 
        FROM logboek.tbl_What 
        WHERE What_name = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ARGUMENTS.myForm.What_name#" />
    </cfquery>
    <cfif LOCAL.myURL.RecordCount eq 0>
        <cfreturn VARIABLES.Error.myReturn />   
    <cfelse>
        <cfquery name="LOCAL.myURL" datasource="#SERVER.cfc.core.getDSN()#">
        UPDATE logboek.tbl_What
        SET What_name=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ARGUMENTS.myForm.What_name#" />;
        WHERE What_name=<cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.myForm.What_name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
        </cfquery>
    </cfif>
```

I rewrote my code but now I get the following error:

> queryError string UPDATE logboek.tbl_What SET What_name='HTML'; WHERE What_name='HTML'.

This is my form code:

```
<form action="blog.Logboek" method="post" name="Update_what">
    <input type="Text" name="What_name" placeholder="Type what you want to update:">
    <input name="requiredFields"type="hidden" value="What_name" /> 
    <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Update_what">
</form>
```

So why can't I update with a form as I want? Can someone give an example of an update with a form?

Comment: Cross reference to previous question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/34874720/1636917

Comment: From where does that semi-colon after `set what_name='HTML'` come?  Voting to close.  This is a simple typo.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing

```
UPDATE logboek.tbl_What SET What_name=<cfqueryparam
cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ARGUMENTS.myForm.What_name#" />;
WHERE What_name=<cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.myForm.What_name#"
cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
```

into

```
UPDATE logboek.tbl_What SET What_name=<cfqueryparam
cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ARGUMENTS.myForm.What_name#" />
WHERE What_name=<cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.myForm.What_name#"
cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
```

I removed the ; at the end of the set What_name row.